# ¿Cómo evitar que el navegador auto-rellene y auto-complete los campos de los formularios?

Tags: html5, angular, google-chrome, autocompletar

Estoy intentando evitar que el navegador web auto-rellene y auto-complete los campos de mis formularios en mi proyecto Angular, ya que se carga los estilos que haya añadido.

[image]

En mi HTML he intentando hacer los campos de solo lectura y luego cuando cojan el foco con un evento de JS quitarles el solo lectura, pero esto solo me funciona para evitar el *auto-rellenado* inicial, luego aparece la ayuda para auto-completar.

```
<section>
    <form novalidate [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onClickSignIn()">
        <img src="assets/images/logo.png"/>
        <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput type="email" placeholder="Email" [formControl]="formGroup.controls['email']" #email appNoAutoComplete readonly>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" [formControl]="formGroup.controls['password']" #password>
        </md-input-container>
        <button md-button type="submit" [disabled]="formGroup.invalid">ENTRAR</button>
        <div id="forgotten-password"><a (click)="onClickForgottenPassword()">¿Has olvidado la contraseña?</a></div>
    </form>
</section>
```

> Directiva para evitar el *autorellenado* inicial.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appNoAutoComplete]',
})
export class NoAutoCompleteDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('focus', ['$event'])
  public onFocus() {
    if (this.el.nativeElement.hasAttribute('readonly')) {
      this.el.nativeElement.removeAttribute('readonly');
      this.el.nativeElement.blur();
      this.el.nativeElement.focus();
    }
  }

}
```

He estado leyendo varios métodos para solucionar mi problema y no he dado con ninguno que funcione correctamente, prácticamente todos dicen hacer lo que está descrito en mi directiva y de poner el atributo autocomplete="off"

Las pruebas las hago en Google Chrome.

#### Actualizo

HTML renderizado.

```html
<app-signin _nghost-c0="" class=""><section _ngcontent-c0="">
    <form _ngcontent-c0="" novalidate="" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]" class="ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid">
        <img _ngcontent-c0="" src="assets/images/logo.png">
        <md-input-container _ngcontent-c0="" class="mat-input-container ng-tns-c1-0 ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid"><div class="mat-input-wrapper"><div class="mat-input-flex"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"
}--><div class="mat-input-infix">
            <input _ngcontent-c0="" appnoautocomplete="" class="mat-input-element ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid" mdinput="" placeholder="Email" type="email" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]" ng-reflect-placeholder="Email" ng-reflect-type="email" id="md-input-1" aria-invalid="false">
        <span class="mat-input-placeholder-wrapper"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><label class="mat-input-placeholder ng-tns-c1-0 mat-float" for="md-input-1">Email <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></label></span></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"
}--></div><div class="mat-input-underline"><span class="mat-input-ripple"></span></div><div class="mat-input-subscript-wrapper" ng-reflect-ng-switch="hint"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "error"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "hint"
}--><div class="mat-input-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c1-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": ""
}--><div class="mat-input-hint-spacer"></div></div></div></div></md-input-container>
        <md-input-container _ngcontent-c0="" class="mat-input-container ng-tns-c1-1 ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched"><div class="mat-input-wrapper"><div class="mat-input-flex"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"
}--><div class="mat-input-infix">
            <input _ngcontent-c0="" class="mat-input-element ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched" mdinput="" placeholder="Contraseña" type="password" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]" ng-reflect-placeholder="Contraseña" ng-reflect-type="password" id="md-input-3" aria-invalid="false">
        <span class="mat-input-placeholder-wrapper"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><label class="mat-input-placeholder ng-tns-c1-1 mat-float" for="md-input-3">Contraseña <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></label></span></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"
}--></div><div class="mat-input-underline"><span class="mat-input-ripple"></span></div><div class="mat-input-subscript-wrapper" ng-reflect-ng-switch="hint"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "error"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "hint"
}--><div class="mat-input-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c1-1 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": ""
}--><div class="mat-input-hint-spacer"></div></div></div></div></md-input-container>
        <button _ngcontent-c0="" class="mat-button" md-button="" type="submit" ng-reflect-disabled="false"><span class="mat-button-wrapper">ENTRAR</span><div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" md-ripple="" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLButtonElement]" ng-reflect-centered="false" ng-reflect-disabled="false"></div><div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div></button>
        <div _ngcontent-c0="" id="forgotten-password"><a _ngcontent-c0="">¿Has olvidado la contraseña?</a></div>
    </form>
</section></app-signin>
```

Comment: Sería bueno que indiques en que exploradores tienes el problema

Comment: Dentro de tu formulario html, en la etiqueta form coloca como atributo lo siguiente `autocomplete="on".`

Comment: @Davlio Google Chrome, actualizo la pregunta.

Comment: Podrías subir la estructura HTML de tu formulario que se muestra en la pestaña _Elementos_ del [DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), para visualizar como se está renderizando.

Comment: @Davlio Pregunta actualizada.

Comment: Prueba usando autocomplete="off" tanto en el form como en el input.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la razón por la que no deseas el autocompletado? Desconozco a qué se refiere el atributo `appnoautocomplete=""` ¿Lo agregaste tu manualmente o ese lo agregó Angular o algún plugin que estas usando?

Comment: @Rubén Es un requisito del cliente. Lo agrega Angular con la directiva creada.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Resumen de una sola línea**: `autocomplete="new-password"`

---

Estás usando un campo de tipo `password`. Independientemente de si tiene la propiedad `autocomplete="off"`, los navegadores preguntarán al usuario si desea guardar la contraseña. Y en el caso que el usuario acepte, el navegador lo va a intentar autocompletar.

Esta funcionalidad fue desarrollada a partir de *Firefox 38*, *Chrome 34* e *IE 11* como una medida de seguridad.

Ya que se considera que gracias a eso, los usuarios pueden poner ahora una contraseña ridículamente complicada (o no) y nunca recordarla, esperando que el navegador sea quien autocomplete sus contraseñas.

De todas maneras, se pensó que para desactivar este comportamiento (el de autorellenar *incluso habiendo guardado la contraseña luego*), se podría usar la propiedad `autocomplete="new-password"`.

```
<input mdInput type="password" 
               placeholder="Contraseña"
               [formControl]="formGroup.controls['password']"
               autocomplete="new-password"
               #password>
```

Sin embargo, `autocomplete="new-password"` no se encuentra implementado en general. Pero de todas formas, si el navegador no entiende el valor asignado, no va a intentarlo demasiado. Por lo tanto; `autocomplete="cualquier-cosa"`, también debería servirte.

Comment: Gracias, está junto con la respuesta de @Einer han sido las que han funcionado. Al final ha quedado el input de email con autocomplete="off" y el de contraseña con autocomplete="new-password" sin mi directiva de por medio.

Comment: perfecto aun me ha funcionado ejejej año 2023

Answer (score 5):

Quizas no sea lo que esperas pero la unica forma en que pude lograrlo fue emulando el input con un `div` y la propiedad `contenteditable`.

Ahora bien, angular no reconoce los div como elementos al igual como lo hace con un `<input type="text" />` por la actualizacion del `ngModel` con cada letra escrita, asi tuve que crear una directiva para que actualizara el modelo siempre que el usuario escriba en el div.

Pido disculpa que el ejemplo esta en [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) 1.* ya que no se [angular2](/questions/tagged/angular2) pero tendras la idea de como hacerlo:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
  
  $scope.modelo = {
    usuario: ""
    
  }
  
  $scope.$watch("modelo.usuario",function(newVal, oldVal){
    console.log(newVal);
  })
}).directive("contenteditable", function($parse){
  return {
    restrict:"A",
    link:function($scope, $element, $attr){
      
      var ngModel = $parse($attr.ngModel);
      $element.on("keyup",function(){
        ngModel.assign($scope, this.innerText);
        $scope.$apply();
      })
    }
    
  }
  
})
```

```css
.editable-div{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

<input type="hidden" ng-value="model.usuario" name="contrasena"/>

  <div contenteditable class="editable-div"
    ng-model="modelo.usuario"></div>
  <div>
    {{modelo.usuario}}
  </div>
 </div>
```

En escencia, lo que hace es que por cada keyup en el div, actualiza el model asignado al div.

Ahora bien, el `form` no reconoce el atributo `name` en un div para enviarlo al servidor. Para eso solo tienes que crear un input[hidden] y asignarle el valor del modelo como esta en el ejemplo. Esto lo deje solo como ejemplo en caso de ser necesario.

Todavia los navegadores no se han puesto de acuerdo sobre que utilizar y ya ves los problemas que eso nos causan. En mi caso me funciono el atributo autocomplete="off" con ponerlo en el form en chrome v60.0.3112.90 y Edge v40.15063.0.0 pero quizas no todo el mundo tenga el navegador actualizado y no todos usan chrome o edge.

No es la solucion mas elegante pero funciona perfectamente. Asi que no se vale puntos negativos.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, tu ejemplo junto con el de @Francute son los que me han funcionado.

Answer (score 4):

Lo que estás intentando, inhabilitar el autocompletado, va contra las premisas que promueven compañías como Google en las que dicha prerrogativa le corresponde al usuario.

Si persistes en la intención, lo primero es intentar lo que recomienda Mozilla Developer Network

1. Usar `autocomplete="off"` o `autocomplete="nope"`

Lo anterior puedes fallar en navegadores como Chrome pues, como se mencionó previamente para Google la prerrogativa del autocompletado es del usuario no del desarrollador. En este caso, cabe recordar que el autocompletado depende de pistas para poder empatar los datos almacenados en el navegador con los datos del formulario como

- la etiqueta `label` de los campos
- los atributos como `name` y `id`

Si te es posible usa etiquetas y nombres únicos.

En lugar de password o contraseña prueba con "santo y seña".
En lugar de Email prueba con identificador

Otra cosa a intentar es duplicar los campos poniendo los primeros escondidos ya que usualmente sólo la primera aparición es autocompletada.

Por otro lado, además de la función de autocompletado de formularios los navegadores modernos tienen como función independiente el guardado de nombres de usuario y contraseñas lo que viene aún más a dificultar que como desarrollador prevengas que estos datos sean llenados de forma automática.

**Sobre el código en stacksnippet**

El OP menciona que `autocomplete="off"` no funciona pero no se incluye en el código, pero por el contrario se incluye el atributo `appnoautocomplete=""`.

**Referencias**

- [How to Turn Off Form Autocompletion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)
- [“AutoComplete=Off” not working on Google Chrome Browser [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18306052/1595451)
- [Chrome Browser Ignoring AutoComplete=Off](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12374442/1595451)
- [Disable browser 'Save Password' functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32369/1595451)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @Rubén, desconocía lo que promueve Google, pero es un requisito del cliente.

Answer (score 3):

Pues tal parece que el `autocomplete` se utilizaba mucho en el pasado en versiones como **IE11, Chrome 34 y Firefox 30**, por lo que no es viable usarlo del todo.
Sin embargo encontré un post algo antiguo en donde se intenta resolver una pregunta similar hay varios caminos a tomar y tal vez uno te funcione. [cómo-deshabilitar-autocompletado-en-formularios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20917/c%C3%B3mo-deshabilitar-autocompletado-en-formularios-web)

NOTA:usar el `autocomplete="off"` en un `input` no funcionara si en el formulario de igual forma esta *on*

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @theboshy pero no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

### Atributo autocomplete de HTML

---

Después de investigar acerca del tema sin encontrar una solución definitiva al problema, que sea sencilla y a su vez respete el estándar ya creado, he decidido programar una solución y compartirla ya que en algún momento cualquier desarrollador se va a topar con este problema pues en algún momento tendrá que crear un **formulario de entrada al sistema (LOGIN)**.

Dicha solución intenta mantener el estándar ya creado y a través de `javascript` hacer que los **exploradores WEB** lo respeten, se trata del Atributo `autocomplete` de [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete#Browser_compatibility)

Aunque el estándar es muy completo al respecto el ejemplo que aquí les dejo solo soporta el valor `autocomplete="off"` a nivel del tag `<form>` e `<input>`.

Ademas pueden colocar un `checkbox` con `id="autocomplete"` para forzar el `autocomplete="on"` como ámbito global para todas las paginas donde utilices este código, (las lineas que controlan esta característica están comentadas en el código ya que *S**O*** no las permite).

Sin mas aquí el ejemplo funcional del código:

```js
autocomplete = document.querySelectorAll("[autocomplete=off]");
if ( autocomplete.tagName = "FORM")
 autocomplete = autocomplete[0].querySelectorAll("input");
     
if ( autocomplete.length ) {
 var elm = document.getElementById("autocomplete") || {};
 if ( elm.name == "autocomplete" ) {
  elm.addEventListener( "change", setAutocomplete );
 // elm.checked = ( "true" === localStorage.getItem( 'autocomplete' ) );
 }
 setAutocomplete(elm);
}

function setAutocomplete(elm) {
 elm = elm.target  || elm;
// if ( elm.name == "autocomplete" )
//  localStorage.setItem('autocomplete', elm.defaultChecked = elm.checked);

 if ( ! elm.checked ) {
  autocomplete.forEach(function(elm) {
   elm.oldReadOnly = elm.readOnly;
   elm.readOnly = true;
   elm.value = elm.defaultValue;
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
   autocomplete.forEach(function(elm) {
    elm.readOnly = elm.oldReadOnly;
   });
  }, 1000);
 }
}
```

```html
<form autocomplete="off">
 <h1>Inicio de sesión</h1>
 <br>
 Nombre de Usuario:
 <input type="text" name="login" id="login">
 <br>
 Clave de Acceso:
 <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
 <br>
 recordar contraseña
 <input type="checkbox" name="autocomplete" id="autocomplete" value="ON">
 <br>
 <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

una forma en la que se podría solucionar este problema sería detectar el cambio en este input, y ejecutar una función donde se le de un valor vacío al campo cuando sea la primera vez que se ejecute.
ejemplo:

```
//Función que se ejecuta al detectar un cambio en el input tipo password 
clearInputs(){
// enableClear en este caso es la bandera que me indicará si es el 
// primer cambio del input (Cuando el navegador lo autocompleta)

if(this.enableClear){
//cambiar el valor del input a ''
this.enableClear = false; 
// se deshabilita la bandera para que no se
// elimine el valor en los proximos cambios

}
```

Answer (score -4):

Has utilizado el atributo `autocomplete` del control input, https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

dejo el ejemplo del link

```
<form action="/action_page.php" autocomplete="on">
First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Ya lo probé, no funciona.